# Python 2.4.3: ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'

Tags: python, logging, config, configparser

Trying to use a logging configuration file to implement `TimedRotatinigFileHandler`.

Just won't take the config file for some reason.

Any suggestions appreciated.

---

x.py:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

logging.config.fileConfig("x.ini")

MyLog = logging.getLogger('x')

MyLog.debug('Starting')
```

---

x.ini:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=trfhand

[handlers]
keys=trfhand

[handler_trfhand]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
when=M
interval=1
backupCount=11
formatter=generic
level=DEBUG
args=('/var/log/x.log',)

[formatters]
keys=generic

[formatter_generic]
class=logging.Formatter
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 5, in ?
    logging.config.fileConfig("x.ini")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/logging/config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    flist = cp.get("formatters", "keys")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/ConfigParser.py", line 511, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'
```

Thanks

Comment: What was the fix?

Answer (score 74):

The error message is strictly accurate but misleading.

The reason the "formatters" section is missing, is because the logging module can't find the file you passed to `logging.config.fileConfig`.

Try using an absolute file path.

Comment: Thank you very much! The exception message was not very helpful. Creating a file called logging.ini solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, @ekhumoro was right. **It seems that `logging` expects an absolute path.** Python team should change this error message to something more readable; it just cannot see my file, not because the config file itself is wrong.

I managed to solve this by defining a `BASE_DIR` variable in a config file and import it as the prefix of the path, just as Django does.  And, remember to create the log file's parent dir(s) if they are not created.

I define the path and the logger in `config.py`:

```
import os
BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import logging
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'utils', 'logger.conf')) # the `logger.conf` locates under 'myproject/utils/'
logger = logging.getLogger("mylog") # 'mylog' should exist in `logger.conf` in the logger part
```

In other modules:

```
from config import logger
...

logger.info("Your loggings modules should work now!! - WesternGun")
```